# qemu-system-x86_64 boot failed

Tags: boot, 16.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I tried to boot ubuntu.iso on qemu-system-x86_64 with command "qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso" but failed, here is warning "TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]"：

[question img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i35u0.png)

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify the guest startup RAM size with the -m option, so the default RAM size is 128M, which is insufficient. For ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso, the minimum size that works is -m 277. To be safe, add -m 512 to the qemu-system-x86_64 options, it should solve this problem.

Comment: This causes a lot of operating systems to not load, so use -m 1G (if you can spare) to be safe

Comment: i got the same problem, but adding -m 512 or -m 1G makes no difference:  the error still pop out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, or something very similar. It gave the same warning and, while it would then boot, it was unusably slow.

I fixed it it by adding `-machine ubuntu,accel=kvm` to the `qemu-system-x86_64` command line.